# My OS is displaying this image, I do not know what it is ... someone could explain

Tags: display, videos

Image next to the system language ... seems to be a blocked video
[image]

---

When I click on it it does not display anything, but it actually popped up after I installed Dropbpox ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the icon for Dropbox manually. Check [here](https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox)

Make sure you have git installed via

```
sudo apt install git
```

then execute

```
git clone https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox /tmp/elementary-dropbox
bash /tmp/elementary-dropbox/install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon itself means that there's a program running and the icon specified in its .desktop file cant be found in any of the icon locations.

Its a common thing with Dropbox for example (if its indeed dropbox let me know if you need a fix)
Other programs might have this behavior as well.

try clicking it and see which program's menu opens